# Displaying steps to maximum profit

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am passing in a sorted vector that contains a data as such:

```
Job Details {Start Time, Finish Time, Profit}
Job 1:      {1         , 2          , 50    }
Job 2:      {3         , 5          , 20    }
Job 3:      {6         , 19         , 100   }
Job 4:      {2         , 100        , 200   }
```

The code finds which jobs are the best for profit by checking all paths that don't overlap for example job 1,2,3 or job 1,4 are possible and it determines job 1,4 is the best value. I am trying to build a function that displays the path on how the code got to the best possible solution.

Ex. Job 1 --> Job 4 --> $250.

But am lost on the implementation.

> Main.cpp

```
    // Find the latest job (in sorted array) that doesn't 
        // conflict with the job[i]. If there is no compatible job, 
        // then it returns -1. 
        int latestNonConflict(vector<Task>someVector, int i)
        {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (someVector[j].getEndTime() <= someVector[i - 1].getStartTime())
                {
                    return j;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        // A recursive function that returns the maximum possible 
        // profit from given array of jobs.  The array of jobs must 
        // be sorted according to finish time. 
        int bruteForceMethod(vector<Task>someVector, int n)
        {
            // Base case 
            if (n == 1)
            {
                return someVector[n - 1].getValue();
            }

            // Find profit when current job is inclueded 
            int inclProf = someVector[n - 1].getValue();
            int i = latestNonConflict(someVector, n);
            if (i != -1)
                cout << someVector[i].getLabel() << "-->";
                inclProf += bruteForceMethod(someVector, i + 1);

            // Find profit when current job is excluded 
            int exclProf = bruteForceMethod(someVector, n - 1);


            return max(inclProf, exclProf);

        }

        // The main function that returns the maximum possible 
        // profit from given array of jobs 
        int findMaxProfit(vector<Task>someVector, int n)
        {
            return bruteForceMethod(someVector, n);
        }

int main()
{
   cout << "The optimal profit is " << bruteForceMethod(tasksVector, 
   tasksVector.size()) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

> Task.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef Task_h
#define Task_h

class Task
{
    public:
        Task();
        Task(string, int, int, int);
        void setLabel(string);
        string getLabel();
        void setStartTime(int);
        int getStartTime();
        void setEndTime(int);
        int getEndTime();
        void setValue(int);
        int getValue();

    private:
        string label;
        int startTime;
        int endTime;
        int value;
};

#endif
```

> Task.cpp

```
#include "Task.h"

Task::Task()
{

}

Task::Task(string inLabel, int inStartTime, int inEndTime, int inValue)
{
    label = inLabel;
    startTime = inStartTime;
    endTime = inEndTime;
    value = inValue;
}

void Task::setLabel(string inLabel)
{
    label = inLabel;
}

string Task::getLabel()
{
    return label;
}

void Task::setStartTime(int inStartTime)
{
    startTime = inStartTime;
}

int Task::getStartTime()
{
    return startTime;
}

void Task::setEndTime(int inEndTime)
{
    endTime = inEndTime;
}

int Task::getEndTime()
{
    return endTime;
}

void Task::setValue(int inValue)
{
    value = inValue;
}

int Task::getValue()
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Can you give use the full code? Including the `Test` struct?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply consider a weighted graph `G` where

- a node is a job
- a node `A` is linked to a node `B` if `A.endTime < B.startTime`
- weight of `edge(A,B)` is `B.profit` (taking the path to B means doing job B)

You want to get the path of maximal weight of `G`.

Usually algorithm want a function to minimize so instead lets take for weight `-B.profit`.

We can always cite the [Floyd–Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm , there is even the path reconstruction algorithm provided in link aforementionned.

#### Home made

But let's do it home-made since it seems to be some homework.

You can do it the *bruteforce* way (which is less efficient but easier to grasp than Floyd Warshall) and check all the longest paths...

create a `root` node to which you add for children all the jobs with their respective weight associated then consider the recursive function:

```
def get_longest_path(node):
    if !node.children 
        return 0

    best_all = {
        w: weight(node, node.children[0]), 
        path: [node, get_longest_path(node.children[0])]
    }

    for node.children as child //starting from 1

        best_path_i = get_longest_path(child)
        //if we found a path with lower total weight (that is, with maximal profit)
        if best_path_i != 0 && best_path_i.weight < best_all.weight
            best_all = {
                w: weight(node, child), 
                path:[node, best_path_i]
            }

    return best_all

get_longest_path(root)
```

note that you can trivially *memoize* `get_longest_path` (to avoid reevalution for an already visited node) without much burden

```
cache = {}
def get_longest_path(node):
    if !node.children 
        return 0

    //node.id is jobId
    if node.id in cache
        return cache[node.id]

    best_all = {
        w: weight(node,node.children[0]), 
        path: [node, get_longest_path(node.children[0])]
    }

    for node.children as child //starting from 1

        best_path_i = get_longest_path(child)
        //if we found a path with lower total weight (that is, with maximal profit)
        if best_path_i != 0 && best_path_i.weight < best_all.weight
            best_all = {
                w: weight(node, child), 
                path:[node, best_path_i]
            }
    cache[node.id] = best_all
    return best_all

get_longest_path(root)
```

No cycles handled but you don't have a job which reverses time I guess

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm can be approached very similarly to a recursive permutation implementation of say a string `ABC` which produces `ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA`.

[Here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20permutation%28head,%20tail%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28len%28tail%29%20%3D%3D%201%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%20%28head%20%2B%20tail%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20range%28len%28tail%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20permutation%28head%20%2B%20tail%5Bi%5D,%20tail%5B%3Ai%5D%20%2B%20tail%5Bi%2B1%3A%5D%29%0Apermutation%28%22%22,%20%22ABC%22%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) is a simple demonstration

You could modify this to "prune" the tree when a condition is not met (eg. the letter after is lower in the alphabet than the previous), so you would get `ABC` as it is the only one where every succesive letter is lower `(A<B<C)`.

Once you have that, you now understand how to recurse over `Task`'s and prune when comparing the `startTime` and `endTime` of jobs...

So here is an implementation of the above in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Task {
    // global counter tracking how many instances
    static int counter;
    int startTime;
    int endTime;
    int value;
    int label;
    Task(int inStartTime, int inEndTime, int inValue) {
        startTime = inStartTime;
        endTime = inEndTime;
        value = inValue;
        label = Task::counter++;
    }
};
// store an index to each Task to keep track
int Task::counter = 1;

// build a search tree of all possible Task sequences
// pruning if next Task and current Task overlap
void jobSearchTree(vector<Task> jobSequence,
           vector<Task> possibleJobs,
           vector<vector<Task>> &possibleJobSequences) {

    for (int i = 0; i < possibleJobs.size(); i++) {
        vector<Task> l;
        for (int j = 0; j < jobSequence.size(); j++)
        {
            l.push_back(jobSequence.at(j));
        }
        l.push_back(possibleJobs[i]);
        // initial recursive call
        if (!jobSequence.size()) {
            vector<Task> searchJobs(possibleJobs);
            searchJobs.erase(searchJobs.begin() + i);
            jobSearchTree(l, searchJobs, possibleJobSequences);
        }
        // test if jobs occur sequentially
        else if (l.at(l.size()-2).endTime <= l.at(l.size()-1).startTime)                {
            // add the Task sequence
            possibleJobSequences.push_back(l);
            vector<Task> searchJobs(possibleJobs);
            // remove this Task from the search
            searchJobs.erase(searchJobs.begin() + i);
            // recursive call with Task sequence as the head
            // and the remaining possible jobs as the tail
            jobSearchTree(l, searchJobs, possibleJobSequences);
        }
    }
}

vector<int> getBestJobSequence(vector<vector<Task>> possibleJobSequences) {
    int maxProfit = 0;
    int totalProfit = 0;
    vector<Task> bestJobSequence;
    for (auto jobSequence : possibleJobSequences) {
        totalProfit = 0;
        for (auto Task : jobSequence) {
            totalProfit += Task.value;
        }
        if (totalProfit > maxProfit) {
            maxProfit = totalProfit;
            bestJobSequence = jobSequence;
        }
    }
    vector<int> jobIds;
    for (auto Task : bestJobSequence) {
        jobIds.push_back(Task.label);
    }
    return jobIds;
}

int main()
{
    Task s1(1, 2, 50);
    Task s2(3, 5, 20);
    Task s3(6, 19, 100);
    Task s4(2, 100, 200);
    vector<Task> allJobs = {s1, s3, s4};

    vector<vector<Task>> possibleJobSequences;
    vector<Task> currentJobSequence;
    jobSearchTree(currentJobSequence, allJobs, possibleJobSequences);
    vector<int> bestJobSequence = getBestJobSequence(possibleJobSequences);
    for (auto job : bestJobSequence) {
        cout << job << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```